# Is the noise at different sampling points related?

Tags: fft, noise, cross-correlation

Given the power spectral density of noise, if the values at different sampling points of the same noise are added, what is the power spectral density at this time? Is there any correlation between the noise at different sampling points?

Comment: Well, that depends on the type of noise. Ideal White noise, for example, is completely decorrelated (its power spectral density is flat). Could you refine your question?

Answer (score 1):

The power spectral density, computed from the magnitude of the Fourier transform of your system $F(\omega)$. If you add two shifted versions of your signal, say $f(t) + f(t + \Delta t)$, in the frequency domain $F(\omega) + e^{-1j \omega \Delta T} F(\omega)$. Then the power spectral density can be calculated $|F(\omega) \left(1 + e^{-j \omega \Delta t}\right)|$

So in summary if the original signal has spectral power density of $p(\omega)$, the new signal will have spectral power density of $ p(\omega) \left|1 + e^{-j \omega \Delta t}\right|$, that can be simplified to  $ 2 \, p(\omega) \left(1 - \cos(\omega \Delta t)\right)$